# WPF HitTesting with UserControl

Tags: .net, wpf, hittest

I have the following UIElement tree taxonomy:

```
<Canvas>
    <UserControl x:Name="A">
        <Ellipse ></Ellipse>
    </UserControl>
    <UserControl x:Name="B">
        <Ellipse></Ellipse>
    </UserControl>
    <UserControl x:Name="C">
        <Ellipse></Ellipse>
    </UserControl>
</Canvas>
```

Currently, the Ellipses Height and Width take up the full Canvas, but their background is Transparent.  The Ellipses can be dragged around the screen.  What I would like to do is perform a HitTest such that

1. The Ellipses can be independently identified when a tap occurs on one.
2. The Ellipses can be dragged around freely (which is why the Height/Width take up the full Canvas).

I did reading on the HitTest documentation, but I'm still confused.  Could someone please provide me with some guidance on accomplishing the above tasks?  In iOS, it was simply overriding the pointInside: to check if the location was inside of the ellipses on the UserControl.

Comment: Use a `Thumb` Control.  You don't need any custom HitTesting for that.

Comment: I'll take a look at the Thumb control, but the UserControl I have is fairly complex.  Could you get a little more into the usage of that control?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to help you with what you want to accomplish.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3bbe949b-ca8a-4a6e-a4fb-a8d267e58931/moveable-imageitem

If you want to identify which children is clicked you can put PreviewMouseDown on parent and check e.OriginalSource for children. If you are overriding the control then you can override Previewmousedown functions to know which children is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

So, in case anyone runs into the same issue, I ended up toggling the Background between NULL and Transparent.  It's kind of a hack, but WPF Routing (Yes I am going to hate) is a huge headache.  I'll probably run into performance issues later (maybe not), but I am able to avoid traversing the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
void UserControl_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    ...
    if (VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(ellipse, e.GetPosition(ellipse)) != null) {
        // mouse is within ellipse
    }
}
```

---

By the way, `UserControl` may be giving you trouble here. Take a look at the explanation of what it does here:

http://books.google.ca/books?id=znAVMHNSen0C&pg=PA518&lpg=PA518&dq=%22taking+a+closer+look+at+user+controls%22&source=bl&ots=DjZT-9JCQd&sig=R4MoAzW72PaHvqgZjxPnkkJRs6c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OdQIUrPgDeTYyAGl6oHYAQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22taking%20a%20closer%20look%20at%20user%20controls%22&f=false

> The UserControl class changes the source of routed events. When events
>   bubble or tunnel from controls inside the user control to elements
>   outside the user control, the source changes to point to the user
>   control rather than the original element. This gives you a bit more
>   encapsulation. (For example, if you handle the
>   UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown event in the layout container that holds
>   the color picker, you'll receive an event when you click the Rectangle
>   inside. However, the source of this event won't be the Rectangle
>   element but the ColorPicker object that contains the Rectangle. If you
>   create the same color picker as an ordinary content control, this
>   isn't the case—it's up to you to intercept the event in your control,
>   handle it, and reraise it.)

This behavior is unique to `UserControl`. Basically, it's meant to group elements together as if they were a single element. The main use-case for it is creating derived controls with a XAML / "code-behind" duo. For stand-alone containers, it's probably better to go with a plain [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx).